# Unreachable Robots.txt in Django app

Tags: django, heroku, seo, django-templates

Received a notice from google webmaster tools that googles crawler bot has stopped crawling one particular site because of an "Unreachable robots.txt." Unfortunately google doesn't give any additional details about the crawler error beyond that.

I have

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
```

included as one of my meta tags in base.html template, which I do for every django app and I'm not having this problem with any of my other sites. Correct me if I'm wrong but I also thought robots.txt isn't necessary to have for google to index you.

I tried to resolve by installing and configuring django-robots (https://github.com/jezdez/django-robots) and adding this to my url conf:

```
(r'^robots\.txt$', include('robots.urls')),
```

My latest google crawler fetch (after pushing django-robots to prod) is still returning the same error though.

I don't have any special crawl rules and would be fine without even including a robots.txt file so google indexes the entire site. Anyone have any thoughts on a quick fix before I just go experiment with the other two methods mentioned here: http://fredericiana.com/2010/06/09/three-ways-to-add-a-robots-txt-to-your-django-project/?

Comment: What do you get when you try to access the robots.txt URL directly?

Comment: Just reach a 404 page

Comment: [According to Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1067240?hl=en) this message means your server at one point was serving a 5xx error message, not just a straight 404. Remove the  robots.txt entry in your urls.py, and try using "Fetch As Google" feature in Google Webmaster Tools to check if this still is the case. You should hopefully get the "Not found" status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried removing the robots.txt line from urls.py completely and fetching as google but that didn't resolve the issue.

```
(r'^robots\.txt$', include('robots.urls')),
```

I fixed this by modifying my root urlconf slightly

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


(r'^robots\.txt$', lambda r: HttpResponse("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /*", mimetype="text/plain")),
```

now googlebot is crawling it ok. Wish I understood better why this specific solution was effective for me, but it works.

Thanks to Ludwik for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

if you have permission then

```
Alias /robots.txt /var/www/---your path ---/PyBot/robots.txt
```

add alias to your `virtual host`. (in apache config file )
similarly for favicon

```
Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/aktel/workspace1/PyBot/PyBot/static/favicon.ico
```